# Set Class from radio:checked to div corresponding with session id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning jquery and I'm hard to build this script.
I need to set the radio class: checked in some divs with class corresponding section of the options .. Good to understand better just give a look at this code.

Who can help since I am already grateful!

Html:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="object" id="obj01">
        <h3>Colors-01</h3>
        <label  class="cor01 cor">01<input type="radio" name="color01"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor02 cor">02<input type="radio" name="color01"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor03 cor">03<input type="radio" name="color01"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor04 cor">04<input type="radio" name="color01"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor05 cor">05<input type="radio" name="color01"  class="rd"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="object" id="obj02">
        <h3>Colors-02</h3>
        <label  class="cor01 cor">01<input type="radio" name="color02"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor02 cor">02<input type="radio" name="color02"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor03 cor">03<input type="radio" name="color02"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor04 cor">04<input type="radio" name="color02"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor05 cor">05<input type="radio" name="color02"  class="rd"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="object" id="obj03">
        <h3>Colors-03</h3>
        <label  class="cor01 cor">01<input type="radio" name="color03"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor02 cor">02<input type="radio" name="color03"  class="rd"></label>
        <label class="cor03 cor">03<input type="radio" name="color03"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor04 cor">04<input type="radio" name="color03"  class="rd"></label>
        <label  class="cor05 cor">05<input type="radio" name="color03"  class="rd"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="obj obj01">Color me</div>
<div class="obj obj02">Hey! More color</div>
<div class="obj obj03">Colorize!</div>
```

Js/jquery:

```
$('.cor').click(function() {
        var cor = $(this).find('.rd:checked').parents().css('background-color');
        var id = $(this).closest('.object').attr('id');
        /** Need a script for set the first class from <label> with radio checked **/
        $('.' + id).css('background-color', cor);
    });
```

CSS:

```
.cor01{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.cor02{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.cor03{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.cor04{
    background-color: coral;
}
.cor05{
    background-color: pink;
}
.obj{
    padding: 2em;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This work good in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oo1s4jm0/, or not ?

Comment: Yep! But i need set the first class. In this fiddle only set background-color. @lmgonzalves

Comment: What do you need to set, what class ?

Comment: The first class from <label> tag father of <radio: checked> (clicked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I update my fiddle, setting selected class to same element that get the background, check if this satisfy your needs:

https://jsfiddle.net/oo1s4jm0/3/

Relevant code:

```
    var classs = $(this).attr('class');
    var first = classs.split(' ')[0];
    var newClass = $('.' + id).attr('class');
    var splited = newClass.split(' ');
    if(splited.length > 2){
        splited[2] = first;
        $('.' + id).attr('class', splited.join(' '));
    }else{
        $('.' + id).addClass(first);
    }
```

Comment: But surely the parent label will end up with all the classes? I think you need to reset it's class first.

Comment: Exactly @jaunt. this work, but unfortunately this reaction occurs.

Comment: Ah, that update fixed it! OP, I think this is what you want. No? :)

Comment: WoW! Nice @Imgonzalves! I knew that the solution was around a conditional, however did not know how to proceed. Thanks! I learned a lot today! Gracias!